# Rolling back an application upgrade

Tags: upgrade, firefox

I don't think an actual rollback or system restore exists in Linux/Ubuntu, so I'm looking at other options to reverse a recent browser upgrade.

I would like to revert to a slightly older version of Firefox than the one installed during a recent upgrade.  The first issue was the narrow scrollbars, but I found a fix for that (use only gtk3 system themes and modify as needed).  But there is another annoyance that's bothering me.  I'm thinking future upgrades will iron out some of the annoyances and/or extensions will be developed to remove the annoyances, since that seems to be the history of Firefox.  In the meantime, it would be nice to revert back to an earlier version.

I found some Firefox .deb files on pkg.com.  That looks to me like the quickest and easiest way to do the reversion. But I have questions.

First, is pkgs.org considered a reputable site?

Second, does one need to completely uninstall the upgraded version of Firefox?  Or can one install the older version on top of the newer version?

**UPDATE:**  Per the suggestion of JonasCz, I looked into installing an official ESR. I uninstalled Firefox 47, which removed everything but kept my profile.  I then downloaded and installed Firefox 45.2 ESR from the official Mozilla link.  Not knowing where to put it, I just installed to a folder in the Home directory, which resulted in the creation of a "firefox" folder.  There are two Firefox binaries -- one that says Firefox and one that says Firefox-bin.  I clicked on the first and Firefox opened with all my bookmarks and extensions.  It seems to be working fine, with the caveat that start-up time is longer... as if it were looking in specific default locations rather than in folders/subfolders in my Home directory.   I think the ultimate solution would be to find a PPA or a .deb file.  I tried a Canonical link to a Firefox [ESR PPA] (https://launchpad.net/~team-esr/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-esr), but it didn't work as there was no file to download.

Comment: You said pkg.com first and then said pkgs.org. Which one of these two are you actually talking about?

Comment: You could also use [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/), which will give you security updates for it as well. I'm sure there's an official repository or PPA for it too.

Comment: Hi edwinksl, it was this link: [link](https://pkgs.org/download/firefox)

Comment: Ho JonasCZ, that looks like a long-term solution worth looking into.

Comment: Jonas, I'll report the results of my PPA search and ESR install in the original post.  I made significant progress.  I just need some fine-tuning.  I'll consider the question answered though since I have successfuly downgraded to Firefox 45.  Thanks for pointing me in the ESR direction.

Comment: EDIT:  The checkmark to mark the question as answered is not visible! Not sure if this is a temporary glitch or the result of the ESR installation.  Maybe a moderator can help.

Comment: For Trusty and Xenial Firefox ESR is available on [Jonathon F's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-esr). firefox-esr package was requested on LaunchPad (see [bug 1676164](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1676164)).